# Why would my pre-approval auto loan be denied, but chance of actual loan approved?

Tags: united-states, loans, auto-loan

I have an income of roughly ~70k, a little over $50k after taxes. My only debts are housing expenses (rent and utilities) which total around $800 out of >$4000 a month net income. Recently, I was rejected for pre-approval on an auto loan for $20,000. However, they said they'd be willing to consider the loan if I brought a purchase order from the dealership.

What's the difference between pre-approval and getting the actual loan? Why would I be denied based on the information I provided?

**Edit:**
My FICO score is 770+. I've checked it a couple times in the past couple months. Once it was 805 and another time it was 777.

Comment: What type of lender rejected you for the loan? A retail bank? An online bank?

Comment: What is your credit score like? Can you also tag your question with a location please? Sorry for all the questions, these details will help get you a good answer!

Comment: It was a local credit union, but I applied online. They requested proof of income, which I gave them.

Comment: Do you have a credit history?

Comment: I've edited the question to include my FICO score.

Comment: I didn't say score I said history.  What's your oldest account?

Comment: @quid My oldest account is a credit card 6 years ago. That particular credit card has a $0 balance, but I keep it open to maintain the history.

Comment: *Why would I be denied based on the information I provided?* did you ask them that question?

Comment: Also - was the loan for a new car or used? Had you provided any parameters about the vehicle you were shopping for? Auto loans are generally approved based on a LTV ratio. Them turning down the "preapproval" yet suggesting they might approve an actual loan on a specific vehicle based on a specific PO may have been based on them hoping that the specific vehicle allowed a good LTV.

Comment: Asking for a *purchase order* makes this sound like a business purchase.

Comment: @RonJohn Yeah, it sounds weird. I thought it would make more sense to ask me to bring them an "intent to sell" or something similar.